# Why does my recursion in Java not result in a StackOverflowError?

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

For testing `StackOverflowError` in Java, I wrote the following code:

```
package recursion_still_not_working;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // System.out.println(fibonacci(50));
        System.out.println("Result: " + factorial(3000));
    }

    public static long fibonacci(long n) {
        if (n > 1) {
            //System.out.println("calculating with " + (n - 1) + " + " + (n - 2));
            return  fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
        } else {
            return n;
        }
    }

    public static long factorial(long n) {
        if (n > 1) {
            System.out.println("calculating with " + n);
            return n * factorial(n - 1);
        }
        System.out.println("base case reached: " + n);
        return n;
    }
}
```

However, only the `factorial` results in a `StackOverflowError`, while `fibonacci` runs through. I am thinking, that there might be some hidden optimization of my JVM going on, which picks up the case of `fibonacci`, but not the case of `factorial`.

What could explain this behavior? To be clear: I expect a stack overflow to happen, but it does *not* happen in one of the two cases, which confuses me. I am *not* surprised by the stack overflow which does happen.

My JVM is:

```
openjdk 11.0.3 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Calling `fibonacci(50)` in fact [crashed this online demo](https://rextester.com/NXES76623).  If it doesn't crash your code locally, try upping the value to something like `100`, it should die eventually.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen For some reason it happily runs and runs on my machine, but of course does not end, as it would simply take too long. The factorial gives me a stack overflow after not even a second of runtime. Also I do not see more and more RAM being used when the programm runs.

Comment: Your `factorial(3000)` runs fine and gives all the results in less than a sec.

Comment: Your fibonacci test uses a way too small value to be comparable. Use the same value for both tests. Also you don't see your program using more RAM, because the Stack runs out of memory, not the much larger Heap space.

Comment: @forpas Well, not on my machine.

Comment: @Tom The thing is, that fibonacci should occupy the stack much faster, as it splits into two calls each time fibonacci is called. Now the program of fibonacci runs for an hour or so, but still no stack overflow, while as I said, factorial runs out of stack space within a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stack Overflow Exception comes, when the Stack is full. So you have repeatedly call a functions inside the function to trigger this situation.

In fibonacci(50) call does not get such a high call depth. The call depth of fibinacci(n) is about n only. But it takes so long, because each call has to do 2 calls, so you end up with 2^n calls that must be done.
But the 2 calls are done one after another so they do not add both to the stack depth.

So to get into the stack overfloe exception, you should:
 - choose a high enough value as parameter
 - set the size of the stack

So you can easily use 3000 as argument and when you call it, maybe use -Xss256k to set the stack size to 256K.

Comment: Now this explanation makes sense! The calls just don't go deep enough, but since it splits in two, there are many calls to compute, but they happen in sequence, not in parallel, which is why they do not take as much of stack space, as they would if they were all "in the depth". I already did the `-Xss256k` thing and setting 3000 works as you describe.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't explain the different behavior between factorial and fibonacci.  Specifically it doesn't explain why one gives an exception when the other doesn't.  The call count does not explain that.

Comment: @StephenC What is missing in your eyes? The call deth is the important point and I mentioned it. So to get the stack overflow, you have to call another function without returning the function till the stack is full. Both functions require the same space on the stack and both have a simple call to itself inside it. So of course: one is called with 50 and the other with 3000. Should I have mentioned that calling a function with a long value 50 times does not need as much space as calling it 3000 times?

Comment: You explained it in more detail in your answer but that is not explaining the "For some reason it happily runs and runs on my machine, but of course does not end". So for me it was more important to explain the difference between the "call depth" (how often is it called without returning) and the number of calls required.

Answer (score 1):

A self-recursive method in Java will cause a `StackOverflowError` if

```
 nos_levels * frame_size + overhead > stack_size
```

where

- `nos_levels` is the depth of recursion required for the problem
- `frame_size` is size (in bytes) of a stack frame for the recursive method,
- `overhead` represents the stack usage (in bytes) of the methods that start the recursive computation (e.g. your `main` method, etcetera)
- `stack_size` is the size of the stack (in bytes).

Now you have implemented recursive versions of the factorial and fibonacii.  Both versions will recurse to a depth of 3,000 to calculate `fibonacci(3000)` or `factorial(3000)`.  And both will be using the same sized stack, and have the same overheads.

The difference that explains why one crashes and the other doesn't is the stack frame size.

Now a stack frame typically contains the following:

- a frame pointer that points to the stack frame for the parent method
- a return address
- the method's parameters
- the method's declared local variables
- any unnamed temporary variables required to hold intermediate values.

The actual count will depends on the code of the method, and on how the JIT compiler maps maps variables to slots in the stack frame.

Clearly, your functions are sufficiently different that they need difference sized stacks.  I have not verified this, but I suspect that it is the `println` statements that are doing this.  Or more specifically, the extra hidden variables needed to hold the intermediate variables used when concatenating the string arguments.

If you wanted to be sure, you would need to look at the code emitted by the JIT compiler.

Comment: While this is a nice answer, and has even some explanation I did not ask for, it seems to me that Konrad has answered the question in the clearest and most related way. Nevertheless, nice answer, thank you.